# New instance of custom objective c class already has data in it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I think I'm missing something pretty fundamental about programming in objective-c.

The callstack is as follows:
MyViewController calls a block to setup a request to my server.

```
[_myClient storePhoto:photo withCompletion: ^(KNPhotoInfo *retPhoto, NSError *error) { // do stuff }];
```

This call sets up a request to my server to save the photo and then tries to handle the response:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) { 
    if(error) //handle it
    @try
    {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        KNPhotoInfo *photoInfo = [[KNPhotoInfo alloc] initWithPhotoDictionary:json[@"data"]];

        [_storage setObject:[photoInfo toDictionary] forKey:PhotoInfoKey];

        completionHandler(photoInfo, nil);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing user info: %@", exception);
    }

}];
```

However if I inspect the photoInfo variable before its init function is called I can see some data (not just garbage) in it. If I step into the init function, when something is assigned I can see the self object flash but then it just says "0 objects" again. After the call to the init funciton has returned, everything seems fine, I can see my object with all it's properties initialized with json["data"], but as soon as I step photoInfo says "0 objects" again.

Can anyone help me out here? I think this has something to do with "self" of the calling class vs self of where the objected is initialized, but I'm confused. :s

EDIT: To add a little more context. The init function looks something like this:

```
- (instancetype) initWithPhotoDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{
    self = [super init];

    self.url                = dict[@"photo"][@"url"];
    self.challenge          = dict[@"photo"][@"challenge"];
    self.user               = dict[@"photo"][@"user"];
    self.pubDate            = dict[@"photo"][@"pub_date"];

    return self;
}
```

However when debugging inside of this call, self has no children (even though it obviously does) and just says "0 objects". What's frustrating about this is when the call to

```
[_storage setObject:[photoInfo toDictionary] forKey:PhotoInfoKey];
```

happens I'm getting complaints about null values. However if I "print description" of photoInfo I can see all of my fields, filled out correctly.

Comment: When you say you have "complaints about null values" in that call, are you breaking on a method in NS[Mutable]Array or NSDictionary?

Comment: What does you mean with <then it just says "0 objects">? Typically objects do not talk. How do you inspect the object? And what are the "children" of self?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad similar to this http://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ALv.png. After fighting with this for a while now, it seems might code is working, and the debugger is just not showing me what I expect. Usually self shows ivars/properties and their values as objects.

Comment: If you're using Xcode's variable view to inspect the properties of an object that hasn't been initialized, then you are indeed seeing garbage. It may just so happen to be intelligible garbage, but it does not reflect a meaningful state of affairs.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right. but I'm still seeing the object as having nothing initialized after initializing it. If I print description I can see all the items filled out correctly, I have to assume the problem is with the xcode debugger?

Answer (score -4):

use this methode

```
- (KNPhotoInfo) initWithPhotoDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
 KNPhotoInfo *photoInfo = [[KNPhotoInfo alloc] init

    photoinfo.url                = dict[@"photo"][@"url"];
    photoinfo.challenge          = dict[@"photo"][@"challenge"];
    photoinfo.user               = dict[@"photo"][@"user"];
    photoinfo.pubDate            = dict[@"photo"][@"pub_date"];

    return photoInfo;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Answers that are simply code or don't actually address the OP's problem are not acceptable here.  If you have any amendments to make this post more informative and helpful, please make them as soon as possible.

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow i have no idea how i make it readable please help me

Comment: Readability isn't really the main problem with this answer.  You can hop over to [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) to see what the community suggests for its new members.  Cheers!